# jQuery Regular Expression to match the Custom String format

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to match the user input with this string. `SA 0000.00.000.B.00`. Just tried the following program. But its not giving right solution.

```
if ($('#svat').length > 0) {
    $('#svat').trigger('keyup');
    $('#svat').on( "keyup", function( event ) {     

        // When user select text in the document, also abort.
        var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
        if ( selection !== '' ) {
            return;
        }

        // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
        if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
            return;
        }

        var $this = $(this);
        var input = $this.val();
                input = input.replace(/[\W\s\._\-]+/g, '');

            var split = 4;
            var chunk = [];

            for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i += split) {
                split = ( i >= 2 && i <= 5 ) ? 1 : 4;
                chunk.push( input.substr( i, split ) );
            }

            $this.val(function() {
                return chunk.join(".").toUpperCase();
            });

    } );    
}
```

It returns like this `1231.2.3.1231.2312.3`. Any good solution from my existing function ?

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please use ***relevant*** tags when posting questions.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: I know which can't be done through jQuery validate.  And I asked a solution with my function. So i am looking a suggestion or solution.  Thanks